# New to InfoPath Forms 2007

Tags: infopath-2007

I am new to InfoPath. My goal is to be able to develop Forms, exposed through Web, supporting Offline mode, submitted later on to Web Applications / Services, etc ...

Is the above doable with InfoPath? Do I need Form Services to run InfoPath? Can I use ASP.NET to host InfoPath forms, like any Web page ?

Books/Resources to start with?

Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable in Infopath. However, can you elaborate on offline mode ?

Infopath forms can either be opened in web browser or in Infopath Client. If you want the forms to open browser, you need Form Services which is nothing but Forms Server.

You can use ASP.NET to host infopath forms. However, if you want them to render in the browser itself, you will also need Forms server.

Check out Infopath developer Center:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/microsoft-infopath-2010-FX101825645.aspx